# Escaping special characters in elasticsearch on document load

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to load some marked up html into a document that is stored in elasticsearch.  What characters besides " s need to be escaped and how do you escape them?

I would like to test via curl (or sense chrome plugin) so I would not be relying on any libraries to do format the text.

```
POST index1/doctype 
{
  "page" : "a",
  "page_time" : "2014-03-19_12-10",
  "html" : "<div class="section" id="idOne"></div>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer.  To escape " s use \ s.